# Height of a JTextArea in gridbaglayout on mac

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm having troubles with setting the height of my JTextArea using GridbagLayout on my mac. On the mac it only shows up as one line, when I run the program on a PC however the height is correct. I've been trying to search around a lot but i haven't come across any solutions, what do you guys think could be the problem?

EDIT:I just noticed that the problem might be located somewhere else in my code.. when i resize my window larger the size become correct, however it still toggles between being a one-line and correct size

This is basically my code:

```
    JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    final JTextArea tArea = new JTextArea("Text", 10, 10);
    final JScrollPane tAreaPane = new JScrollPane(tArea);
    tArea.setLineWrap(true);
    tArea.setRows(15);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    center.add(tAreaPane, c);
```

Ive tried setting:

```
    tArea.setSize(200,400);
    tArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    tArea.setBounds(5, 5, 100, 100);
```

on both tArea and tAreaPane. Where am I doing it wrong?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I just noticed that the problem might be located somewhere else in my code.. when i resize my window larger the size become correct.. however it still toggles between being a one-line and correct size

Comment: I see such abrupt changes with `GridBagLayout` on Mac OS X, but I've never chased it down.

Comment: `I just noticed that the problem might be located somewhere else in my code.` And that is why a SSCCE should be posted. Until the solution is found you don't really know what code is relevant. Are you building the GUI on the EDT?

Comment: Obviously the problems is the look n feel for mac and the UI class it uses. I had a similiar problem. When I solved it on one platform I got another problem on another platform. I finally switched back to the default look n feel, which is really ugly, but it was the only way to have the same rendering on every platform.

Comment: @Daniel did you find out any solution for the question? I am also facing the same problem...???

Answer (score 2):

Set preferred size ot tAreaPane rather than tArea.

Answer (score 1):

your [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) issue is caused by code line for [JTextArea's instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

[final JTextArea tArea = new JTextArea("Text", 10, 10);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29)

and [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) pretty accepting `PreferredSize` came from defined `Columns & Rows` for [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)